# My Flutter app doesn't update when i restart it and loads an old version of the app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I searched and only found old answers that didn't work for me, any new solutions?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing changes inside app and update your app with hot reload or hot restart, these changes will be discarded when app kills or restart.
So re-run your app to get new changes

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the older version from your phone. After that try to restart your project.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Run Flutter clean,make sure your build directory deleted after flutter
clean,if not run flutter clean until it removes from project,

Step 2:Uninstall the app from phone or emulator

Step 3:Run project again